# Wavefront Alerting when no data sent

Tags: wavefront

I have wavefront alerts set up with the following alert condition:

ts(mytimeseries)<20000

Recently the datasource stopped sending data to wavefront but I did not receive an alert. I cannot figure out why this did not alert. Do I need to set up a separate alert for when data is not sent. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes in scenarios where there is no data sent you explicitly need to define the condition for that. Well the best approach is to create a new availability alert but still if you want to manipulate the same condition you can do something like below

```
default( 20001 ,ts(mytimeseries))<20000
```

In case there is no data found it will exceed your limit and will raise the alert